# Is there a way to convert SWF to HTML5

Tags: html, flash, file-conversion

Since Swiffy is gone, I was wondering if there are still ways to convert an SWF to HTML5?

Answer (score 10):

If it is Actionscript 3, you can use: http://www.createjs.com/zoe

If it is Actionscript 2, you run into problems. My hope is that Swiffy will become an open source project in the future. If so, it should be available [on github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=swiffy&type=).

Probably the best solution:

[Ruffle](https://ruffle.rs/) "is a Flash Player emulator built in the Rust programming language". Which also works with flash input fields that could not be converted by Swiffy. To be able to work it needs to load the "wasm" file (5 MB, compressed 1.8 MB).

Other Software found:

- [Adobe Wallaby](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/wallaby/wallaby_p1_win_030811.exe) (install [Adobe Air](https://get.adobe.com/air/) beforehand, not working with AS2 fla-files)
- [Flabaco](https://www.flash-banner-converter.com/) (only for banners)

Commercial products:

- SWF to HTML5 converter (not tested): http://www.fla-exporter.com/
- Adobe Flash Professional CS6 can publish FLA files as HTML5
- Adobe's Animate CC can export FLA files to HTML5, [read here](https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/using/creating-publishing-html5-canvas-document.html)

And from the [Swiffy site](https://developers.google.com/swiffy/):

> Developers who currently create Flash SWF files have several ways to switch to HTML5 including Adobe Animate and Google Web Designer. If you need to play an existing Flash SWF file in your browser alone, you might be able to use Mozilla’s Shumway.

- [Adobe Animate](http://www.adobe.com/products/animate.html) (free trial)
- [Mozilla Shumway](https://github.com/mozilla/shumway)
- [Google Web Designer](http://www.richmediagallery.com/resources/googlewebdesigner)

Comment: This question is old, but current solution that works very nicely for a subset of documents is ruffle:

https://ruffle.rs/#usage

Comment: "Ruffle is a Flash Player emulator written in Rust." → Question is: "Is there a way to convert SWF to HTML5". Your emulator does not solve the question.

Comment: Yes, but for the 99% case of this question - people don't really care about converting it - they just want their old flash stuff to run on a current web browser - and depending on what content it is (language coverage/etc.), Ruffle will let you do that drop-in.

Comment: I have checked the demo: https://ruffle.rs/demo/ Impressive, it also works with flash input fields that could not be converted by Swiffy. For the web version (self-hosted), I guess it always needs to load the wasm file (5 MB, compressed 1.8 MB) to work. But that's actually okay.