# How can flash file be loaded on Android App?

Tags: android, flashplayer-10

I have url of flash epaper which can be opened by Adobe flash player and I want to display on android app , how can it done?

**Note:** http://www.enayapatrika.com/enayapatrika.com/ep/2018/5/30/

Comment: Transform your fla or swf into html5. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050917

Comment: Flash isn't supported on Android.  In fact, Flash shouldn't be used everywhere-  even its creator has given up on it as hopelessly insecure.

Comment: then how can epaper be displayed on app?