# Play SWF with HTML5 or possible conversion

Tags: ios, html, flash, actionscript

1- I have swf files(also have flash .fla) created using ActionScript 1.0, I want to convert them to HTML5. Is there any tool to convert it?

2- Is there any work around to play swf on iOS? I have 2000 swf files that need to be played on iOS as well. Any idea or possible work around?

Thanks

Comment: This thread might be helpful
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050917/5807290

Comment: It talks about Actionscript 3 and Actionscript 2. My problem is even worse, how to deal with Actionscript 1?

Comment: For **point 2**, you could try using Adobe AIR to create an iOS app. AIR has a browser API (that could possibly load those AS1 files). You'll just have to try and see.